# Can you enter jannah just by pray juma(friday prayer)?

Tags: salat, jannah, jumuah

I don't pray 5 times, I only pray juma salah(Friday prayer) so would I enter jannah if I only pray Friday prayer?.  Another way of asking same question is are you still a muslim if you only prayer Friday prayer?

Comment: All sahaba were in consensus that a person who doesn't pray or pay zakat is not a Muslim. As a Muslim you can't chose whether you pray only jumu'ah or your daily prayers as this would mean you accept some of your duties and deny some (kufr).

Answer (score 1):

Jannah is for all those who believed in Allah and associated no partners with Him at death.

> It is narrated on the authority of Jabir b. Abdullah:
>
> I heard the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) saying: He who met Allah without
>   associating anything with Allah entered Paradise and he who met Him
>   associating (anything) with Him entered Fire.
>
> [Sahih Muslim 93 b](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/1/176)

**But does this mean a sinful muslim will not enter Hell?** No, not at all.

> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives
>   what is less than that ***for whom He wills.*** And he who associates others
>   with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin.
>
> [Quran (4:480)](https://quran.com/4/48)

So if Allah wills the sins will be forgiven. But if not, then the person will taste HellFire till he/she has been punished for his/her sins or if Allah wills be released from Hell at an earlier time through His Mercy.

> It was narrated that Abu Sa'eed Khudri said:
>
> "The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: 'When Allah has saved the believers
>   from Hell and they are safe, none of you will dispute with his
>   companion more vehemently for some right of his in this world than the
>   believers will dispute with their Lord on behalf of their brothers in
>   faith who have entered Hell. They will say: " Our Lord! They are our
>   brothers, they used to pray with us, fast with us and perform Hajj
>   with us, and you have admitted them to Hell." He will say: "Go and
>   bring forth those whom you recognize among them." So they will come to
>   them , and they will recognize them by their faces. The Fire will not
>   consume their faces, although there will be some whom the Fire will
>   seize halfway up their shins, and others whom it will seize up to
>   their ankles. They will bring them forth, and will say. "Our Lord, we
>   have brought forth those whom You commanded us to bring forth." Then
>   He will say: "Bring forth those who have a Dinar's weight of faith in
>   their hearts, then those who have half a Dinar's weight in their
>   hearts, then those who have a mustard-seed's weight." **Abu Sa'eed said.
>   :"He who does not believe this, let him recite, 'Surely, Allah wrongs
>   not even of the weight of an atom (or a small ant), but is there is
>   any good (done), He doubles it, and gives from Him a great reward.**'"
>
> [Sunan Ibn Majah -  Vol. 1, Book 1, Hadith 60](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1250600)

Why would anyone want to experience Hell even for a nano-second is beyond me. It is better for you to try to pray the 5 fard prayers daily. If you are a man and are unable to make it to the masjid, start with praying at home. Inshallah Allah will make easier for you and provide a means to the masjid too.

If you are unable to leave your office desk for prayer, try praying while in your cube. Or if you drive and a masjid is not closeby, pray in the car or a parking lot.

The Sahabas are considered among the best of humankind after the Prophets. Many of them had one common thing that depressed them. They were sad that they didn't convert to Islam sooner and raked in more rewards.

Remember Jannah is not just a single huge plane. There are levels in jannah and our goal should be *Jannutul Firdaus.*

May Allah make it easy for you and all of us to pray our salaats and fulfill our religious duties. Ameen.